# how to create custom calendar in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

I want to set my favorite date to calendar and calendar should work according to my date.

I want set my calendar date to 10/2/2107 and it must increment it is day after each day, I mean when I open my application tomorrow calendar date must be change to 10/3/2017 and when I open the day after tomorrow the date must be change to 10/4/2017 and so on....

I try this code
**this.monthCalendar1.TodayDate = new System.DateTime(2017, 10, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0);**
but when I open my Application calendar get the system date I don't need the system date I need my own calendar date.

for more Details I add a few pictures.
[when I open my form today calendar must looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l06z.png)

[when I open my form tomarrow calendar must looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ady8.png)

[the day after tomorrow it must looks like this and so on...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQuyx.png)

Comment: this.monthCalendar1.TodayDate = DateTime.Now;

Comment: thanks dear Ramankingdom but if I use DateTime.Now my calendar is affected by system date I want my calendar should not be affected by system date. I want to set my calendar to 10/2/2017 and after each day it changes it is date like 10/3/2017, 10/4/2017, 10/5/2017 and so on... Thanks again

Comment: Is it winforms?

Comment: yes it is. it is winform

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your problem. You have a form on which you are showing a MonthCalendar. 
Now you want to set the today date of calendar to a different date. And when you open that form tomorrow the date should be auto incremented.

The best way to do that is

1. Define an offset let say OffsetDays which is an int and can be positive and 
   negative in settings  as shown in [image: pic]
2. For e.g if you want to set the date 10 days earlier the offset OffsetDays 
   value would be -10 and positive if you want to show 10 days ahead.
3. Now on you form load

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       monthCalendar1.TodayDate = 
       DateTime.Now.AddDays(Properties.Settings.Default.DaysOffset);
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks again your solution is best solution, it solved 60% of my problem, but one thing else I need, When the user changes it is system date my App calendar date should not be affected by that changes, is it possible, I need my App calendar must be independent of system date, any change in system date should not affect my App calendar. I set my calendar date to 10/2/2017 and then I follow the information you shared but when I opened my App it is date was affected by my system date.

Comment: In that case assume your minimum date. and add offset to it.

Comment: But you should always have a reference date . The best way to be independent from system is to get from server via service

Comment: My system is winApp and it is not connected to any server, but I use sql server with my App is it possible to get the date from sql server to make my App independent